# How to write a file then read it back to verify its contents, ensuring you're getting what's on the disk not the cache

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, filesystems

I'm using native/C++/Win32/MFC code on Windows to save a document file via MFC serialization.  I've inserted my own CFile-derived class in the writing process giving me access to the data as its being written.  This allows me to compute a checksum (or hash, etc) on the data as its going out to the file.

After the files has saved, I'd like to allow the option of verifying the file.  The idea would be to re-open the file and read through it verifying the checksum/hash/etc.

I'm wondering, though, if its possible that after having just written the file, the OS could be giving me unwritten data when I read the file back right away.  In this case, the test doesn't really tell me that the file looks good on the disk.

Is my concern valid?  If so, is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: Write to file. Close handle.  Fill RAM with useless buffers to force flush.  Delete buffers.  Read file. (Won't work if computer has more RAM than virtual process space)

Comment: @Ambeco What's more it will have a horrid impact on any other processes on the machine.

Comment: I don't think I want to fill RAM as part of this process tbh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using **CFile**, you can call **[CFile::Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d9chxf7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** to ensure everything is written to disk. According to the documenatation

```
virtual void Flush( );
```

> Forces any data remaining in the file buffer to be written to the file

Comment: My guess would be, that like all other file abstractions, this just flushes the program's cache to the operating system. There is no guarantee this actually flushes to the disk.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y but if you use another OS call to read the data back again...it will be correct regardless

Comment: perhaps just closing the file and using a new CFile to open it would accomplish that then?

Comment: @Nerdtron Just flush the buffer. My understanding is that Windows will ultimately tell the disk driver to flush the buffer to disk. If the disk driver doesn't do that ("performance optimisation"), then there's not much you can do about it. I don't have it handy, but I believe there's a few blog posts by SQL Server's PSS that mention this issue as a leading cause of log file corruption. But basically: Tell Windows to flush the file and it should flush the file. Unless the disk driver lies to it, in which case there's no recourse for Windows or you to detect this scenario.

Comment: @todda.speot.is I wonder...  If MFC creates a CFile and writes out the data then closes it, can I create a different CFile object for the same disk file and just open it for writing, call Flush then close it and have the same affect?  The problem is, I don't have the CFile MFC used after the save is completed.

Comment: @Nerdtron I can't find any documentation on MSDN that guarantees that the file will be flushed when it is closed, but note that [`Close` is `virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6ka6t4.aspx) - you say that you derive from `CFile`, so perhaps override `Close` to be `Flush(); CFile::Close();`?

Comment: @todda.speot.is excellent point!  thanks!  And as I read your comment I realized I already am deriving from the class so I can filter the write ops.. duh :)

Comment: @Nerdtron I haven't stepped in MFC source code in a while but you can step into CFile::Close and CFile::~CFile and see if flushing is done for you

Comment: @parapura rajkumar I checked the source.  CFile::Close() just does a ::CloseHandle(), so it looks like I need to call CFile::Flush() which calls ::FlushFileBuffers().

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this then you can avoid disk caching and buffering by specifying [`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx#file_flag_no_buffering) and/or [`FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx#file_flag_write_through) when opening the file. Beware that using these options will complicate things.

> The file or device is being opened with no system caching for data reads and writes. This flag does not affect hard disk caching or memory mapped files.
>   There are strict requirements for successfully working with files opened with **CreateFile** using the **FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING** flag, for details see [File Buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950.aspx).

A simpler alternative is to call [`FlushFileBuffers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439.aspx) just before you close the file handle.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the answer to this question.  However, I do know where to look.

[SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) guarantees that data is safely written to disk, no matter what happens - even a power failure.  They must be doing what you need, their code is open source and beautifully commented.

> All changes within a single transaction in SQLite either occur
>   completely or not at all, even if the act of writing the change out to
>   the disk is interrupted by
>
> a program crash,
>
> an operating system crash,
>
> or a power failure.
>
> The
>   claim of the previous paragraph is extensively checked in the SQLite
>   regression test suite using a special test harness that simulates the
>   effects on a database file of operating system crashes and power
>   failures.

http://sqlite.org/transactional.html

Comment: interesting, thanks for the tip!  I'll take a look at their code.

Comment: SQLite don't guarantee that because it's impossible. Not until somebody invents disks that run without power!!!

Comment: @David Heffernan  Please read the SQLITE guarantee, which I have posted in my answer.

Comment: That guarantee isn't what you say in your answer. You said data is written to disk even when the power goes off.

Comment: @David Heffernan I said safely - means completely or not at all.

Comment: @ravenspoint I believe this is because SQLite keeps a small journal in each database, which is a mechanism external to the operating system. Note that the guarantee isn't that *data* is written completely or not at all, it's that *changes* are written completely or not at all. There can still be crap floating around in the file if a power failure interrupts the commit, but the journal knows about this.